How do you pin rows to the top of a v-data-table so they are unaffected by Header sort in Vue3?
My goal is to have some rows of a data table always be 'pinned' to the top of the table, regardless of column or customized search. I have a previous project I worked on using Vue2 that this functionality was simple.
Here is the working Vue2 code:

headers: [
    { text: 'Fiscal Year', value: 'fiscalYear', class: 'tableHeader' },
    { text: 'Facility(s) name', value: 'facilityNames', class: 'tableHeader' },
    { text: 'Status', value: 'externalStatus', class: 'tableHeader' },
    { text: 'Submission Date', value: 'submissionDateString', class: 'tableHeader' },
];
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="currentFacilities"
     mobile-breakpoint="md"
     fixed-header
     class="elevation-4 my-4"
     disable-pagination hide-default-footer
     :sort-by="['priority', 'submissionDate']"
     :sort-desc="[true, true]" >

      <template v-slot:item.facilityNames="{ item }">
          <div class="tableTooltip">{{ item.facilityNames }}</div>
      </template>

      //... more column data here
 </v-data-table>


In the Vue3 code - I would also like to sort by the priority value that I assign, with the rows with a priority of 1 always at the top, and the other rows would get sorted as the user chooses based on headings.
I am able to get the rows with highest priority sorted to the top on first load, however, when the user clicks the headings, they are just sorted normally.
If anyone has got this functionality to work in Vue 3 I would be super grateful for the help!
I tried using the above syntax in my Vue3 project, and I was not able to get the rows to stay pinned to the top. I have read the Vue documentation, but I have not found this specific use case outlined.
